# "Out of all people" vs "of all people"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which sounds the most correct and natural: *of all* or *out of all*? For example:

> **Out of all** the people I know Kate sings the best.
>
> **Of all** the people I know Kate sings the best.

If both are perfectly fine, then which one is more common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct and sound totally natural, so you can't really go wrong here. That said, I believe "Of all the people..." is likely more common because brevity is used wherever possible by most native speakers.

I think the more common way of saying the same thing would actually be to arrange the sentence differently and say "Kate sings better than anyone else I know" or "Kate is the best singer I know". These sound more natural to me because they put the subject (Kate) at the beginning of the sentence